# Why, after removing duplicates, the array length is 0?

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to print the "unique_words", and it prints "hostname1 hostname2 hostname3", which is correct. However, when I check its size, it is 1 instead of 3. Why that happened?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Define the string value
text="hostname1 hostname2 hostname2 hostname3"
RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)
declare -i x=1

# Set space as the delimiter
IFS=' '
#Read the split words into an array based on space delimiter
read -a hostArray <<< "$text"
unique_words=($(echo ${hostArray[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq))
echo ${#unique_words[@]}
```

Comment: I have fixed my code, but now the size is 1 instead of 3

Comment: And what are the contents of the array?

Comment: It is "hostname1
        hostname2
        hostname3"
but the size is 1. I guess maybe all the 3 hostnames are in the first entry of the new array?

Comment: Hint: what variable is important when splitting a string into array elements?

Comment: Is it the variable 'IFS'?

Answer (score 1):

When you assign the output of `uniq` to the array `unique_words`, `IFS` is still set to a space. However, the output of `uniq` consists of several lines, i.e. words separated by newline characters, not spaces. Therefore, when you define your array, you get one single multiline string.

If you would do a

```
IFS=$'\n'
unique_words=($(echo ${hostArray[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq))
```

you would get 3 array elements.

Alternatively, you could save the old value of IFS before changing it:

```
oldifs=$IFS
IFS=' '
read ....
IFS=$oldifs
unique_words=....
```

**UPDATE**:

As was pointed out in a comment, saving IFS in this way is not a good solution and in particular can't be reliably used if `IFS` was unset in the beginning. Therefore, if you just want to restore IFS to its default behaviour, you can do a

```
IFS=' '
read ....
unset IFS
unique_words=....
```

Comment: `IFS=' ' read -a hostArray <<< "$text"` sets `IFS` for the `read` command alone, preventing it from affecting any other commands.

Comment: Saving and restoring `IFS` is tricky.  See [Is it a sane approach to "back up" the $IFS variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264926/264812).

Comment: @pjh : The discussion you linked to, is helpful. I didn't know that saving is not reliable if `IFS` was originally unset (which seems the most serious one of the problems being discussed). I will amed my response accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and `IFS` to convert strings to arrays is difficult to do safely, and is best avoided.  Consider this ([Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean) alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

words=( hostname1 hostname2 hostname2 hostname3 )

sort_output=$(printf '%s\n' "${words[@]}" | sort -u)
readarray -t unique_words <<<"$sort_output"

declare -p unique_words
```

- In Bash code, it's much better to use arrays (like `words`) instead of strings to hold lists.  In general, there are significant difficulties both in looping over lists in strings and in converting them to arrays.  Using only arrays is much easier.
- `echo` is not a reliable way to output variable data. Use `printf` instead.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).
- `readarray` (aka [mapfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile)) is a reliable and efficient way to convert lines of text to arrays without using word splitting.
- `declare -p` is an easy and reliable way to display the value, and attributes, of any Bash variable (including arrays and associative arrays).  `echo "$var"` is broken in general, and the output of `printf '%s\n' "$var"` can hide important details.